# Selection is not working for third selection

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, aura-if

I write following component code :

```
<aura:component controller="TransactionsalSecurity" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction">
<aura:attribute name="toggleGer" type="boolean" default="true" />
<aura:attribute name="noggleGer" type="boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="toggleEng" type="boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="toggleBng" type="boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="set" type="object" />

<!--aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />


<div class="slds-align_absolute-center ">
    <lightning:select name="mySelect" label="Select a TransactionalList" aura:id="mySelect" onchange="{!c.boggle}">
        <option>Report</option>
        <option>API</option>
        <option>None</option>
    </lightning:select>
</div>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleBng}">
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center ">
        <lightning:select name="mySelection" label="TransactionalSecurityGrouping" aura:id="mySelection" onchange="{!c.toggle}">
            <option>None</option>
            <option>Today</option>
            <option>Access</option>
            <option>API</option>
            <option>Dashboard</option>
            <option>Data</option>
            <option>EmailDocuments</option>
            <option>LoginPolicies</option>
            <option>Manage</option>
            <option>Report</option>
            <option>System Config</option>
            <option>User</option>
        </lightning:select>
    </div>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.toggleGer}">
        <table class="slds-box slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer ">
            <thead>
                <tr>


                    <th scope="col">
                        <span class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="height:2rem" title="User Name">Name</span>
                    </th>

                    <th scope="col">
                        <span class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="height:2rem" title="QueriedEntities">QueriedEntities</span>
                    </th>

                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="height:2rem" title="Permission Set Name">Format</div>
                    </th>

                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="height:2rem" title="Permission Set Name">EventSource</div>
                    </th>

                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="height:2rem" title="Permission Set Name">NumberOfColumns</div>
                    </th>

                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture" style="height:2rem" title="Permission Set Name">Operation</div>
                    </th>





                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.set}" var="perm">
                    <tr class="slds-text-color_weak slds-text-font_monospace">

                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.Assignee.Name}">{!perm.Name}</div>
                        </th>

                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.Assignee.Profile.Name}">{!perm.Assignee.Email}</div>
                        </th>

                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.QueriedEntities}</div>
                        </th>

                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.Format}</div>
                        </th>

                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.EventSource}</div>
                        </th>

                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.NumberOfColumns}</div>
                        </th>

                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.Operation}</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </aura:if>
</aura:if>
```

Following is my controller code:

```
({
toggle: function(component, event, helper) {
    var sel = component.find("mySelection");
    var nav = sel.get("v.value");
    if (nav == "Today") {
        component.set("v.toggleGer", true);

    } else if (nav == "API") {
        component.set("v.toggleGer", false);
        component.set("v.toggleEng", false);
    } else if (nav == "None") {
        component.set("v.toggleGer", false);
        component.set("v.toggleEng", false);
    }
},

boggle: function(component, event, helper) {
    var sel = component.find("mySelect");
    var nav = sel.get("v.value");
    if (nav == "API") {
        component.set("v.toggleBng", false);
    } else if (nav == "Report") {
        component.set("v.toggleBng", true);

    } else if (nav == "None") {
        component.set("v.toggleBng", false);

    }
},

doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    //call apex class method
    var action = component.get('c.TransactionalSecurityToday');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        //store state of response
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            //set response value in ListOfAccount attribute on component.
            component.set('v.set', response.getReturnValue());

        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }

})
```

The problem here is that  when i select Report the value it display is ok. All values which i want are displayed but my third condition that i want table to be displayed only for today condition but for every other condition table is displayed by default can someone correct me where iam wrong here i want table to be display only in condition when my selection is "Today"

Answer (score 0):

You need to call boggle function in the toggle function so that it will refresh you attributes based on your conditions.

Also add `component.set("v.toggleBng", false);` into toggle function

Below is the code for JS Controller

```
toggle: function(component, event, helper) {
helper.toggle(component, event, helper);
}
boggle: function(component, event, helper) {
helper.boggle(component, event, helper);
}
```

Below is the code for JS Helper

```
toggle: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.toggleGer", false);
    component.set("v.toggleBng", false);
    var sel = component.find("mySelection");
    var nav = sel.get("v.value");
    if (nav == "Today") {
        component.set("v.toggleGer", true);

    } else if (nav == "API") {
        component.set("v.toggleGer", false);
        component.set("v.toggleEng", false);
    } else if (nav == "None") {
        component.set("v.toggleGer", false);
        component.set("v.toggleEng", false);
    }
    this.boggle(component, event, helper);
},


boggle: function(component, event, helper) {
    if (component.find("mySelect")) {
        var sel = component.find("mySelect");
        var nav = sel.get("v.value");
        component.set("v.toggleBng", false);
        if (nav == "Report") {
            component.set("v.toggleBng", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is giving me error @Chetan Nandre on any selection This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:TransactionalSecurity$controller$toggle [Cannot read property 'boggle' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:TransactionalSecurity$controller$toggle

Comment: Make sure that above code you have added in Helper JS. I have edited answer you can have look in above solution

Comment: See here the problem is that everytime table is displayed it doesn't work on my selection i want table to be displayed on for Today selection please read my component code and my requirement

Comment: Can you add this in 1st line component.set("v.toggleGer", false);  inside the toggle function

Comment: Thanks all their is one silly mistake for me toggleger is set true by default that was giving error always.

Answer (score 0):

your table visibility controlled by `toggleGer` boolean attribute that you declared with `true` by default that means your table shown always, first take out default `true`. then control for show/hide in your click function.